# How to preserve name of file in collection in xslt transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have a collection of files I process in an XSLT transformation. The collection looks like this (not sure I can actually use a name attribute here):

```
<collection stable="true">
    <doc href="3690096.xml" name="3690096"/>
    <doc href="3690214.xml" name="3690214"/>
</collection>
```

In my transformation I use the collection in a variable `<xsl:variable name="my_collection" select="collection('collection.xml')"/>` and use `$my_collection` in a for-each loop to to create a html page for each xml file:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="$my_collection">
            <xsl:result-document href="{concat('item_', position(),'.html')}" method="html">
                <xsl:call-template name="separate_page_for_file"/>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

As you can see above, I use `position()` and the results are `item_1.html` and `item_2.html`.

What I want to achieve is to preserve the original ID of the file. So the desired outcome is `3690096.html` and `3690214.html`.

A stretch goal is to have these IDs available for other stuff too, because I have corresponding images with those IDs (like 3690214_0.jpeg, 3690214_1.jpeg and so on), that I could look up.

In general I can address the name via `//doc/@name`, but not when I am in context of the for-each loop for $my_collection.

Comment: Why do you need the collection as collection at all? Could you not simply create a result document for each `doc` in the collection.xml file?

Comment: I probably could, but it seemed to be a neater way to handle many files (I just used two as an example).

Comment: What difference does it make?

Comment: What I do is creating an index page with an overview of all documents as cards, with some information like a title from the document itself. At the same time those cards have a link (like 3690096.html) on them, to go the full document. At the moment I create the href for the link the same way for buttons and result-documents, but not only need the filename, but also information from inside those documents. it's of course quiet possible, that I don't understand the concepts fully and am on the wrong track all together. It just seemed to be a solution.

Comment: If you do `<xsl:for-each select=doc('collection.xml')/collection/doc">` you can then create a result document using the value of `@name` of the current `doc`, as well as get any information from (or even apply templates to) the corresponding document using `doc(@href)`.  At least so it seems from your description (you did not provide a reproducible example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check whether e.g. `<xsl:result-document href="{base-uri() => replace('\.xml$', '.html')}" method="html">` works. For me it does [with Saxon HE 11 Java](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/?code=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cresult%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each%20select%3D%22collection%28%27https%3A%2F%2Fmartin-honnen.github.io%2Fxslt%2F2023%2Fcollection-example1.xml%27%29%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cprocessing%3E%7Bbase-uri%28%29%7D%3C%2Fprocessing%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aresult-document%20href%3D%22%7Bbase-uri%28%29%20%3D%3E%20replace%28%27%5C.xml%24%27%2C%20%27.html%27%29%7D%22%20method%3D%22html%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aresult-document%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acomment%20xmlns%3Asaxon%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fsaxon.sf.net%2F%22%3ERun%20with%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-name%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-version%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27Q%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fsaxon.sf.net%2F%7Dplatform%27%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Acomment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fresult%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=&code-type=XSLT&input-type=None) and [Saxon HE 12 Java](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/index-saxon12api.html?code=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cresult%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each%20select%3D%22collection%28%27https%3A%2F%2Fmartin-honnen.github.io%2Fxslt%2F2023%2Fcollection-example1.xml%27%29%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cprocessing%3E%7Bbase-uri%28%29%7D%3C%2Fprocessing%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aresult-document%20href%3D%22%7Bbase-uri%28%29%20%3D%3E%20replace%28%27%5C.xml%24%27%2C%20%27.html%27%29%7D%22%20method%3D%22html%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aresult-document%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acomment%20xmlns%3Asaxon%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fsaxon.sf.net%2F%22%3ERun%20with%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-name%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-version%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27Q%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fsaxon.sf.net%2F%7Dplatform%27%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Acomment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fresult%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=&code-type=XSLT&input-type=None).

Mike's suggestion is to use e.g.

```
    <xsl:for-each select="uri-collection('collection.xml')">
        <xsl:result-document href="{replace(., '\.xml$', '.html')}}" method="html">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="doc(.)"/>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

if I understand that right. If you have a named template expecting each document of the collection as the context node you can use

```
    <xsl:for-each select="uri-collection('collection.xml')">
        <xsl:result-document href="{replace(., '\.xml$', '.html')}}" method="html">
          <xsl:for-each select="doc(.)">
            <xsl:call-template name="separate_page_for_file"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: This leads to the following error:
SXWN9000  The only value that can pass type-checking is an empty sequence. The required item type of the first operand of '/' is node(), but the supplied expression {fn:base-uri(...)} has item type xs:anyURI

Comment: @sleepyhead, do you get that error for the `<xsl:result-document href="{base-uri() => replace('\.xml$', '.html')}" method="html">` (which in turn you have inside e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="$my_collection">`) or elsewhere? If so, for which XSLT/XPath?

Comment: Exactly, I got that error whe replacing my xsl:result-document line from the example above with your suggestion. The whole thing is part of `<xsl:template match="/">`, where some other things are happening and I suppose the error is pointing to this.

Comment: I can't see why you would get that error if the outer `for-each` does the `<xsl:for-each select="$my_collection">`, that way the `base-uri()` should work and the calling of `replace` on it with e.g. `=> replace('\.xml$', '.html')` too. Which version of Saxon is that exactly?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I did something wrong before and the content of the file got deleted, which left an empty xml and not much to work with... It actually works and creates the html file in the same folder of the xml file :)

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through `$my_collection/collection/doc` and then you can refer to `@href` and `@name` inside of the loop.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this approach once again, but it seems like I cannot address the docs in this way. It does not give me an error, but also no results.

Comment: With a bit of a hacky way `//collection/doc` works though. I suppose I have to think this through a bit more, because I want to preserve the filename, but at the same time I want to use further templates on the content of those file, that are not available like this (this is were I need my variable again)...

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of history here. In the past Saxon's `collection()` function always returned documents that had a document-uri() property which usefully identified them. But then we found that didn't satisfy the rule that no two files are allowed to have the same document-uri(), so we changed that. You can follow some of the history starting at https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5640

I think the simplest solution in your case might be to call `uri-collection()` in place of `collection()`. This gives you a set of URIs to work with, and you can retrieve the corresponding documents by calling `doc()`.

Alternatively, as Martin suggests, if your collection is actually controlled by an XML catalog file, then you could just process the referenced files individually.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the short history or pointer to the history of collections! I tried this out for a bit but I think the rest of my xslt kind of gets in the way 